# Where is Windows 10 activation key?

Tags: windows, windows-10, license, windows-activation, license-key

So, I'm having big trouble trying to fix my friend's computer.
She stopped a Window's update shutting down the computer (I know, it hurts just to read).

Now the PC is not booting. I tried everything to fix Windows, but not succeeding.
So I copied the two partitions (Data & OS) onto another hard disk, so I have a copy of everything. I wiped down the hard drive and clean installed a copy of Windows 10, using the ISO downloaded from the Microsoft official site.

And here the problem arrives: there isn't any sticker with Window's activation key on. And the key is not anywhere else.

So I'll have to bring it out from the backup. And here I'm needing help: where do I find this key? It is even findable or is encrypted and not decryptable?

Comment: It’s stored in the ACPI table.  You don’t need to know the license key to install or activate Windows 10

Comment: Just install Windows 10.  It’s literally that easy.

Comment: Granted, you'll have a watermark in the bottom-right of your screen but otherwise, you don't need the product key to install windows.

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 What type of watermark are you talking about?

Comment: For next time know that you should have used System Restore to revert the machine back to its pre-failed update state instead of reinstalling Windows.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator It is an external program or a feature of Window's recovery?

Comment: @Fly_7113 its a built-in capability.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator If so, I tried even that, without succeeded though

Comment: @Fly_7113 Here's an example. [Example](https://linustechtips.com/main/uploads/monthly_01_2016/post-262628-0-69454200-1453769540.png)

Comment: Did you try to use produkey ? I had good success even with licence keys entered in the bios

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 Oh, I got it. I thought you were meaning something like a sticker or similar. Didn't had the idea you were talking about the actual screen

Comment: @FluffyDestroyer I'll try this out, and I'll let you know if it works or not

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 you only get a watermark if windows can't activate. With windows 10, you can run the setup, skip entering a license key and usually windows is still activated automatically. If that is the case, no watermark will show up, so your information is false.

Comment: Also, the product key can be extracted from an older backup. You will need the SOFTWARE hyve which is located in C:\Windows\System32\Config. Copy all files that begin with SOFTWARE. Once you have these, download NirSoft ProduKey and open the SOFTWARE file and it will show you the license key that was used on the previous install.

Comment: @LPChip I had a bit of research on the internet and found something similar to what you're suggesting, so I'll definitely try this (and let you know)

Comment: An activated Windows 10 system will reactivate after reinstall automatically if the same version was installed. This question should not be, where is my product key? But, why didn’t windows activate? In which case the answer is likely that you installed the wrong version of Windows 10. I.e. if the system came with home, install home edition. If it came with pro, install pro. Otherwise the system wasn’t activated to begin with. Come to think of it, we haven’t actually answered the question if Windows is or is not activated?

Comment: @LPChip Evidence to support this?

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 How about dozens of installations as experience? But yeah, google it, its pretty known. Even written here on SuperUser.

Comment: Well, you get no watermark for 30 days... If you have digital entitlement then you'll have no watermark forever... If it's an install on a new system, you'll get a watermark. Sorry for not clarifying my statement.

Answer (score 0):

So, I just pointed out what my problem was: wrong Windows version.
In fact I installed the pro edition instead of the home, which was my case.
During the installation I hadn't to insert the license key, because it was still in the computer.
Thanks a lot to the people who helped me down in the comment section of the question

Comment: I'll mark the question as answered the sooner I can